# How do I properly use serialize to save arrays and hashes to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm obviously missing something fairly fundamental in my use of serialize. I'm trying to save several arrays and hashes to a database record, which I pull from various other records in my controller. I list them on a page to check them before saving, and have them posted in hidden fields to my create action. They are definitely hashes and arrays when I use them in my page view. However for some reason they get saved as escaped strings. Here's example code:

Model:

```
class Bulletin < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :news
  attr_accessible :news
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@bulletin) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :news %>
  <%= f.submit "Create bulletin", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
...
def new
  @bulletin = Bulletin.new
  create_news
  ...
end
def create
  @bulletin = Bulletin.new(params[:bulletin])
  ...
end
...
private
  def create_news
  ...
  if @bulletin.news == []
    @bulletin.news = [["No news", "No news submitted this week."]]
  end
end
```

I've literally included the bare minimum of code there for you to get it. There is more code in the create news function for instance which actually generates a nested array of news if it exists.

I should also note that I did have `serialize :news, Array` but it threw up an error "Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String".

Edited to add -

Generated HTML (ie. input):

```
<input id="bulletin_news" name="bulletin[news]" type="hidden" value="[[&quot;Bulletin User&quot;, &quot;A whole lot of news.&quot;], [&quot;Bulletin User&quot;, &quot;A whole lot of news.&quot;]]" />
```

These are pairs of values pulled from a test database, and joined into a nested array. There's a lot more than that, I cut it short for readability.

Output when querying the record from console:

```
"[[\"Bulletin User\", \"A whole lot of news.\"], [\"Bulletin User\", \"A whole lot of news.\"], [\"Another User\", \"A whole lot of news.\"], [\"Mr. Jovany Murazik\", \"A whole lot of news.\"]]"
```

Comment: Could you post an example string which is being saved into the database? They *should* be saved as escape strings, but encoded, so that when you call Model.news the string is decoded. Please post your example input/ouput from the DB.

Comment: Edited question to add example form input, and example output.

Comment: It could be because you're entering an array in string format in your `value=""`. That is why when you specified `serialize :news, Array` it returned an error "was a string".

Comment: have you tried escaping the output with raw in the view?

Comment: I have no idea how to submit anything other than a string in the value. That's generated by the formbuilder, which I assumed would automatically submit it as an array, if it knows that it's serialized as an array in the database. I guess it doesn't though. Is there a way to tell rails to submit the data as an array?

Comment: Escaping the output doesn't help, as I still can't access the values within the hashes or arrays. If I reference @bulletin.news in the show view, it prints the array to the page, but if I reference @bulletin.news[0][0] to get the first nested value, I get "["

Comment: All forms *ever* do is submit strings. If you want to deserialize it in your controller so AR can serialize it, you need to do that manually. Also, not a big fan of `create_news`'s side effect--it requires more reading than necessary to know that it modifies an instance variable. Consider having it return a value, or put it in the model.

Comment: Okay thanks to your comment I got it to work Dave. I stripped the form down so it basically does nothing, which is probably better anyway since an invisible form seems a bit dumb. Then I just added logic in the create action for generating the record to submit to the database. Works a treat.

Also on your advice the `create_news` no longer modifies an instance variable. I created a separate variable for it and assign them in the main action. So cheers. :D

Comment: Also if you'd like to submit your comment as some form of answer I'll accept it. :)